# How to 'cancel' the stream data response after request another one

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of Expandable Items, each time I click in one of the items a stream is called returning a list of another items related to that I clicked on. The problem is if I quick expand two items of my initial list, the last remains with the items from the first one.

Example of what is expected:

```
(EXPANDABLE LIST)
Colombia
   (items showed when I click on Colombia)
   Bogotá
China
   (items showed when I click on China)
   Beijing
```

Example of what happens if I quickly open two items:

```
(EXPANDABLE LIST)
Colombia (clicked first, and before the load quickly click on China)
China
   Bogotá
```

Is there a way to close or cancel or pause the stream every time I expand one item?

UPDATE
SCREEN

```dart
return ExpansionTile(
              leading: items[index].image == null || items[index].image.isEmpty ? Image.asset(ASSET_NOIMAGE_URL,
                  fit: BoxFit.scaleDown
              ) : Image.network('${BASE_ROUTE_URL}/${ROUTE_SLASH}/${items[index].image}', fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,),
              title: Text('${items[index].code}  |  ${items[index].desc}', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: AppColorSecondary),),
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.75,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  child: CountryDetails(items[index]),
                ),
              ],
```

WIDGET

```dart
class _CountryDetailsState extends State<CountryDetails> {
  Country country;

  @override
  void initState() {
    country = Provider.of<Country>(context, listen: false);

    country.load(produtoGradeFVList: Provider.of<CountryListProvider>(context, listen: false).produtoGradeFVList).then((value) {
      
    }); // here the stream is feed

    super.initState();
  }
```

Comment: If you could show some code, it could help finding a solution

Answer (score 0):

You could set a debounce duration on the stream controller to avoid receiving two requests within a very short interval of time as:

```
_cityController.stream
  .debounceTime(const Duration(milliseconds: 500))
  .listen(_handlerFunctionForTapEvent);
```

Here, _cityController is your StreamController that's listening to the tap events of expandable items from the ui. Try setting a debounce time of 500 milliseconds, hopefully that would fix the issue.

Or you could also send the name of country along with the list of cities in the response from the stream and perform a check in the ui before displaying the city names in the expandable list.

Comment: where should I put this?

Comment: I don't have listeners, just when the item is tapped I call 'load' to get the stream values at initState

Comment: hello, are you there?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the late response. Could you please add the code regarding how you fetch the data on tap?

Comment: Please see my update

Comment: It's still not clear how and where are you making the use of streams. So if your data is not so big I would suggest you to fetch all the countries along with the cities and use the same values instead of fetching the name of cities each time a country is selected.

Comment: Every time I click on Expansion tile, it opens a new CountryDetail.. In country detail's init state I call the method load which gets data from the stream

Comment: You could then send the name of the country along with the cities response from provider and use it to compare with the expanded country and decide whether to show that data or not.

Comment: update your answer with the provider too so we can have a better understanding of the code

Comment: I can't just compare the name I send because in the moment I compare may not have all the content loaded in stream.

Comment: The provider you asked for is a normal one, which gets data from the DB.. Without anything different from usual